# Octave print to cmd prompt

Tags: matlab, console, octave

Using the Octave GUI, we can easily print to the console, for instance via:

```
disp('Print this');
```

However, what if I want  to print to a console outside of the Octave GUI console? I know I can run Octave without the GUI, but I'm not interested in that. I want to use Octave running through the GUI to open up a new console (like in Windows via cmd) and print to that console.

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function `dispcmd` and call it instead of `disp`.

```
function dispcmd(in)
    fid = fopen('temp-disp', 'w+t');
    fdisp(fid, in);
    fclose(fid);
    system('start cmd /Q/C "type temp-disp && pause>nul"');
end
```

Comment: Now if I call this a few time in my Matlab script, it opens up a new cmd prompt each time. What if I want to keep writing to the same one?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. That isn't a trivial Octave task and I think it requires calling some Win32 API functions from c/c++.